Persistent Thudding/Rattling Noise After Bathroom Remodel
I recently had a bathroom remodeling project done in my home, which was built in the 60s. The project involved converting tubs into standing showers and replacing old toilets and vanities in multiple bathrooms. For the downstairs bathroom, there was additional re-piping work to switch the locations of the toilet and vanity.
Since the remodeling was completed about a month ago, I started noticing a thudding sound whenever I turn on or off water fixtures like sinks, toilets, and showers. The faster I turn the water on or off, the louder the thudding noise becomes.
Before the remodeling, my water pressure was around 100 PSI, and I never had this issue, though I occasionally heard a whistling sound when the water flow was too low.
I had a plumber come out and replace the pressure reducing valve (PRV) installed in the crawlspace today. The PSI went down to 50, but that didn't fix the issue. We opened a couple of walls behind the downstairs and upstairs showers to see if we could find any pipes making the rattling sound, but we couldn't find anything.
We tried turning off the shutoff valves at each bathroom to isolate the issue, but that didn't work either.
I also tried installing one water hammer arrestor at the cold shutoff valve of one vanity but didn't seem to help either.
I'm really at a dead end here and not sure what to do next. It's been a stressful week, and I'm feeling very anxious whenever the bathroom or kitchen is being used. I keep thinking something bad will happen, like a burst pipe. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cold or hot or both? If hit, depending on how pipes were secured, thermal expansion/contraction can sometimes produce a repeating click due to friction.

It's probably just an inadequately secured pipe or pipes "somewhere". Locating that problem precisely could be very disruptive and expensive. That sort of noise is just a nuisance, it will not cause pipes to break or burst. It might be best just to learn to open valves slowly.
